# How to calculate $\int(5x)^4e^{-2x}dx$ without using IBP?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

How do I integrate this?

(UPDATE: Sorry, I should have clarified that I've been told to use the gamma function and not just integration by parts, also that this is a definite integral.)

$$\int_{x=0}^\infty (5x)^4e^{-2x}dx$$

I know that that  $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty w^se^{-w}dw = s!=\Gamma(s+1)$, and I've been told to apply this fact, but I can't figure out how to apply this second equation to the first equation above.

I can simplify the first equation as follows:

$$= 5^4\int_{x=0}^\infty x^4e^{-2x}\,dw $$

Then if I let $w = 2x$, I can get to:

$$= \frac{5^4}{2^4} \int_{x=0}^\infty w^4  e^{-w} \, dw$$

But I'm not sure what to do next!

Comment: integration by parts!

Comment: The thing you "know" is a fact about definite integrals. This question is about indefinite integrals.  Use integration by parts.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang should I ignore the gamma function? I've been told to use it.

Comment: The gamma function might be relevant if you were doing an improper definite integral. Your question appears to be about indefinite integrals. Or are you not writing the limits of integration?

Comment: *checks question* Yes, sorry, I didn't add the limits. It is a definite integral. Apologies!

Comment: I don't understand the $i=$ in the lower limit. But it seems like you already have a definite integral that is Gamma of something.

Comment: Um, okay. Confused now. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Evaluate $I(a)=\displaystyle\int e^{ax}~dx$, and then repeatedly differentiate both sides with regard to *a*.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting there just continue your work using IBP not via substitution. But to simplify your computation note that the integral after putting the constant outside the integral sign satisfies a special type of IBP which is via tabular method. Just comment if you have questions.

I got $-e^{-2x}(\frac{625}{2}x^4+625x^3+\frac{1875}{2}x^2+\frac{1875}{2}x+\frac{625}{4})+C$.

I think you must have a definite integral if you want to use  the given formula.

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused :( if I use IBP then what should I let equal `u` and what `v`?

Comment: Just set aside the constant for now. And try to integrate $x^4e^{-2x}$. By using IBP I know that it is too long. Just use tabular method. Differentiate $x^4$ till it reaches 0. Integrate $e^{-2x}$ till the number of expression to the left is similar to the right. Left is a table for derivative right is for the integral.

Comment: I see, it is a definite integral my bad ^^,.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to change the limits also. When one changes the variable of integration he has to change the limits accordingly. The new limits will be the range of the function $f(x)=2x$ in the domain $(0,\infty)$ which is $(0,\infty)$, thus your last expression should be 
$$= \frac{5^4}{2^4} \int_{w=0}^\infty w^4  e^{-w} \, dw.$$

Can you conclude from here?

Answer (score 0):

You are so close!  Notice that since $w=2x$,
$$
\frac{5^4}{2^4}\int_{x=0}^\infty w^4 e^{-w}{dw} = \frac{5^4}{2^4}\int_{{\color{green}w}=0}^\infty w^4 e^{-w}{dw}
$$
And now you substitute your known fact
$$
\frac{5^4}{2^4}\int_{w=0}^\infty w^4 e^{-w}{dw} = \frac{5^4}{2^4}4!
$$